# AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The following is a task, which is throwing me an error because jinja2 templating doesnt support this.

```yaml
- name: Print the ip address
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_{{ item }}['ipv4']['address'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_interfaces|reject('search', 'lo')|list|sort }}"
```

The error thrown is:

> "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'. String: {{ ansible_{{ item }}['ipv4']['address'] }}"

Any pointers on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lookup` plugin `vars`. For example

```yaml
    - name: Print the ip address
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_ifc.ipv4.address|default('Undefined') }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces|reject('search', 'lo')|list|sort }}"
      vars:
        my_ifc: "{{ lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ item) }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth0) => 
  msg: 10.1.0.27
ok: [localhost] => (item=wlan0) => 
  msg: Undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use jinja2 expansion when you are already inside a jinja2 expansion expression. In other words [mustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names).

In your case you can use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html) to fetch your dynamically named var:

```yaml
- name: Print the ip address
  vars:
    interface_var_name: "ansible_{{ item }}"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', interface_var_name)['ipv4']['address'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_interfaces | reject('search', 'lo') | list | sort }}"
```